# How to run Azure Function app according to different time zone like check one user in utc and one user in est, need to send 10am on there timezone

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I am using azure function app for for sending email but it is running according to set time every 5 min 10 min hours and every days.
But i want to schedule timmer according to diffrent timezone one email goes to utc persion accroding to florida timezone on 10am and second is goes to est timezone on there 10am.

Comment: You should stick to one timezone that is UTC. If email is sent at 10am Florida time then you shoud convert it to UTC and schedule the azure function to that time.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions uses **UTC** as its default time zone. Agree with the comment by `@chetan`.

If your Azure Function App is based on windows, then try to add the below new  `Application Setting`  to your Function App called as **‘WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE’** like below screenshot.

[image]

For Windows host based Function App, check the time zone [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)).

***Reference:***
[NCRONTAB time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-time-zones).